# How to use ctrl key + mouse click to select multiple controls?

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Probably this question has already an answer here but I was not able to find it..
I have a tabControl with a flowlayoutpanel in each tab page where I can add controls at run time. I can rearrange them, move them across tab pages.. How can I select multiple controls to be able to move them around using ctrl key + mouse click?

This is my drag event so far:

```
private void control_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Control target = new Control();

        target.Parent = sender as Control;

        if (target != null)
        {
            int targetIndex = FindCSTIndex(target.Parent);
            if (targetIndex != -1)
            {
                string cst_ctrl = typeof(CustomControl).FullName;
                if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(cst_ctrl))
                {
                    Button source = new Button();
                    source.Parent = e.Data.GetData(cst_ctrl) as CustomControl;

                    if (targetIndex != -1)

                        fl_panel = (FlowLayoutPanel)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0];
                    if (source.Parent.Parent.Name == target.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name)
                    {
                        this.fl_panel.Controls.SetChildIndex(source.Parent, targetIndex);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        target.Parent.Parent.Parent.Controls.Add(source.Parent);
                        this.fl_panel.Controls.SetChildIndex(source.Parent, targetIndex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private int FindCSTIndex(Control cst_ctr)
    {
        fl_panel = (FlowLayoutPanel)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.fl_panel.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            CustomControl target = this.fl_panel.Controls[i] as CustomControl;

            if (cst_ctr.Parent == target)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: This is a feature of the designer built into Visual Studio.  There is no support for this whatsoever at runtime, the designer view of your form is radically different with an overlay window that can do things like display the selection rectangle.  Just clicking a control already gives you a headache, that of course triggers the control's MouseDown event.  The VS designer is a multi-man-year effort, not something you are going to get started with an SO question.  Taking advantage of the designer yourself is [covered here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163634.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy, nor a common task. But surely doable and depending on preconditions could become trivial without need to spend multi-man-year effort on it ^^.

You have many options:

- controls support selection;
- container control support children controls selection;
- overlay.

Handling selection is pretty easy: have a dictionary (or a control property, possibly using `Tag`) to store if control is selected or not, show selection somehow, when control is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-clicked invert selection. You can even provide <kbd>Shift</kbd>-key selection.

As @Hans Passant commented, you can use overlay window (invisible window on top of everything) to draw selection reticle there as well as handle selection and dragging itself. Or it could be a custom control with property `IsSelected`, setting which will draw something (border?) to indicate selection.

Easiest option would be to create `SelectionPanel` control, which can host any other controls inside, has `IsSelected` indication and is draggable. When children is added subscribe to `MouseUp`/`MouseDown` events or you can only allow to drag if special area of `SelectionPanel` is clicked. To example, you could have option *Enable dragging* in your software, when set all `SelectionPanel`s will display special area (header?) which you can drag or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click.